# How to connect react native app to java server

Tags: java, react-native, server

I've created a java server app which opens connections with serverSocket on port 3000 and it works perfectly with java client app I created. But now I started developing client app in react native and I can't understand it's socket API, because socket.io in react native forces me to use WebSocket way.
Is there any other way?

```
public static final int PORT = 3000;
private ServerSocket mServerSocket = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            close();
            return;
        }

        while (isOpen()) {
            try {

                mSocket = mServerSocket.accept();
                ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread(new Client(mSocket, this));
                mClients.add(clientThread);
                clientThread.start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
            }
        }
        try {
            mServerSocket.close();
            mSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please have a look here: https://github.com/davidstoneham/react-native-sockets

Comment: But it only works with Android right? "Java Socket Native Plugin for React Native for Android"

Comment: since you connect against a server socket, I would assume it to work also in standard Java Clients

Comment: But how can I make it work with iOS?

Comment: Pudiste solucionarlo? yo estoy intentando con socket.io